# update function parameters on some other function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

here i am stuck in my app with comments. i am making an app facebook like. where comment button take me to specific post is viewed on ionicModal. and i can comment on that post. My problem is i can comment on that post i cannot update it instantly where i have to close my modal and reopen to view updated data.
Here's my code

feed is ng-repeat value

```
<div ng-click="commentModalOpen(feed)">
```

the modal code is

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/comment.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function(modal) {
          $scope.commentModal = modal;
        });
        $scope.commentModalOpen = function(feed) {
          $scope.commentModal.show();
          $scope.feed = feed;
        };
```

where $scope.feed show me my post on ionicModal and update comment on modal

```
 <textarea ng-model="obj.postcomment" id="postcomment" placeholder="Your Comment" autofocus="true"></textarea>
   <div ng-click='btn_add(feed.PostId,obj);' >Post Comment</div>
```

the btn_add add my comments although want to show my updated comment on the ionicModal it self which im not able to 
suggest some solution 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, the following example will clear things up. I recommend testing it out on [play.ionic.io](http://play.ionic.io)

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="MainCtr">
        <button class="button button-assertive" ng-click="openModal()">I'm a button</button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>

    <script id="my-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">My Modal title</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <div ng-repeat="obj in feed">
        <div>{{obj.text}}</div>
        <div> 
          <textarea ng-model="obj.postcomment" id="postcomment" placeholder="Your Comment" autofocus="true"></textarea>
          <button ng-click="obj.text = obj.postcomment">post</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic']).controller('MainCtr', function($scope, $ionicModal) {

  $scope.feed = [
      {text:'fb is dumb ~la', postcomment:''}, 
      {text:'no it\'s not lol', postcomment:''}];

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

});
```

Comment: i think you miss understood my query. i want to post my comments on ionModal and update it instantly when i click btn-add() fn. althought  i am not able to it coz i have beeen send my post via function so while opening my modal. where the fields comment should update instantly

Comment: I still don't understand without a complete example. Can you create an example isolating the problem on the [ionic playground](http://play.ionic.io)? Just click save and share the url